# Testing remote WebSphereMQ queue managers

Tags: ibm-mq

I'd like set up a battery of tests for testing new installations of QMs. Most of them will be in a "remote" setup. I'd like to be able to send a message to the new QM and receive a response. Is there any way to make a "loop" just with normal configuration (i.e. without using exits) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways to do this. It rather depends on whether you want to include the MQPUT and MQGET on the remote system target queue.

- Define the target queue as a QREMOTE pointing back to the originating system again with a real QLOCAL as the final destination back on the original system.
- Use something like SupportPac MA01 (Q program) to echo the message back when it lands on a real QLOCAL queue on the remote system. The -e option let's you echo the message back to the ReplyToQ and ReplyToQMgr fields.

Comment: The MA01 with Echo option allows an attacker to send it a message with *any* ReplyTo values and, assuming it is started as an MQ service and running as `mqm`, then have their message placed on any queue.  The method using normal queues and QRemotes is preferable because the messages can be strictly contained within the defined route.  I've provided sample object definitions for this method in my answer and some thoughts on naming conventions and security based on how it's been implemented in various shops.

Answer (score 5):

My former employer was a bank and we had many connections to clearing 
houses and other vendors.  On many of these I was able to have the business partner set up loopback queues on their end.  These consisted of a QRemote on my QMgr that pointed to a QRemote on the other side, which pointed to a QLocal on the originating QMgr on my side.  When a message is `PUT` to the QRemote it flowed to the other side, landed on the QRemote there, then was directed back to the QLocal.

If the message didn't make it back, we would then start our inbound channel (which was defined as a `RQSTR` on our side).  If this caused the channel to start and the message arrived then we knew the channel initiator on the other side was down but at least we could keep the channel running until it was fixed.  But if this didn't work we knew there was some problem on their side other than channel triggering.

And, yes, this was production.  We figured that non-transactional instrumentation messages are valid in Production environments.  As far as we were concerned, this was the same as a ping or cluster control message.  Of course, we had a web screen and other instrumentation to kick them off so usage of the utility was controlled and were recorded.

There are similar methods in which QMgr aliasing is used and this can greatly cut down on the number of loopback queues needed in a large network.  Do NOT be tempted to do this!  When we use QRemotes that specify a fully-qualified destination, all they can do is send and receive loopback messages on the prescribed queue.  But if a QRemote is used without an `RQNAME` then it can be used to send messages to *any* queue on the adjacent QMgr.

Let's say you have `QMA` and `QMB`:

```
runmqsc QMA
DEFINE QLOCAL(QMB.LOOPBACK) REPLACE
DEFINE QREMOTE(QMB.LOOPBACK.RMT) +
       XMITQ(QMB) +
       RQMNAME(QMB) +
       RNAME(QMB.QMA.LOOPBACK.RMT) +
       REPLACE
END

runmqsc QMB
DEFINE QREMOTE(QMB.QMA.LOOPBACK.RMT) +
       XMITQ(QMA) +
       RQMNAME(QMA) +
       RNAME(QMB.LOOPBACK) +
       REPLACE
```

Now you can go to the server hosting `QMA` and do:

```
echo Hello World | amqsput QMB.LOOPBACK.RMT QMA
```

Note that the name of the loopback reflector on `QMB` has *both* QMgr names in it.  This is because you probably want to set up lopback from both sides and cannot use `QMB.LOOPBACK.RMT` both as a reflector *and* to initiate loopbacks.  In that case the object inventory looks more like this:

```
runmqsc QMA
DEFINE QLOCAL(QMB.LOOPBACK) REPLACE
DEFINE QREMOTE(QMB.LOOPBACK.RMT) +
       XMITQ(QMB) +
       RQMNAME(QMB) +
       RNAME(QMB.QMA.LOOPBACK.RMT) +
       REPLACE

DEFINE QREMOTE(QMA.QMB.LOOPBACK.RMT) +
       XMITQ(QMB) +
       RQMNAME(QMB) +
       RNAME(QMA.LOOPBACK) +
       REPLACE
END

runmqsc QMB
DEFINE QREMOTE(QMB.QMA.LOOPBACK.RMT) +
       XMITQ(QMA) +
       RQMNAME(QMA) +
       RNAME(QMB.LOOPBACK) +
       REPLACE

DEFINE QLOCAL(QMA.LOOPBACK) REPLACE
DEFINE QREMOTE(QMA.LOOPBACK.RMT) +
       XMITQ(QMA) +
       RQMNAME(QMA) +
       RNAME(QMA.QMB.LOOPBACK.RMT) +
       REPLACE
END
```

Note that all of the objects sort out based on the name of the remote QMgr.  Some people prefer names like `LOOPBACK.QMB.RMT` to make all the loopback queues cluster together in a list of objects or a backup.

All of this is a great target for automation since the names of the objects can all be derived from the names of the QMgrs.